# Blazor App CS0103 error when build on Jetbrains Rider when no no error when using VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, rider

Having some free time I decided to start with C#, .NET, and Blazor pages.

Started with default Blazor page template (to examine how it works) and found that

- when trying to build it on Jetbrains Rider 2020.01 it raise an `App.razor(3, 32): [CS0103] The name 'routeData' does not exist in the current context`
- exactly same template (haven't found any differences) build on VisualStudio 2019 without any problems

As I couldn't find anything and I am a newbie in .NET world any direction I should look?

Comment: Can you find where routedata was set on statup?

Comment: @Shane_Yo: I can't. As I stated I am new to .NET and C# but I checked all source files included in starting template

Comment: I am taking a stab, you should have a Global.asax,cs that calls something like RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes) You you should start there

Comment: @Shane_Yo: Thank you for pointing out a direction. There is no such file in project tree but at least I have an idea what I might be looking for. (Besides of that same base template runs fine when on Visual Studio)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER Report to JetBrains and see how they respond.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing your steps, i experienced the same error that you've had...
The reason is.. Jetbrains Rider's generated project is  the same, because AFAIK Rider uses the default project generator(dotnet).

> just reopen the project, if that does not work, create a new project using `dotnet new blazorserver -o [your project name here]` or just open the project generated in VS using Jetbrains Rider

I do not know what the reason of such error is.. But this solution helped me, and i hope that it will help you too..
If that does not help, feel free to comment it out..